# How to create a list dialog using Dialogfragment and ArrayAdapter to populate items from Java class?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I am learning DialogFragments myself. I have never tried anything than passing intent from a Button, so I am not getting to right direction.

I want to learn all the possible ways.

Is it different than creating a list with ListFragment?

There are 2 buttons on main Activity. On clicking the second Button, it should open a DialogFragment with a list of items, clicking on a list item should open a URL in the browser.

Main Activity

```
btnDepartment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DepartmentActivity.class);
                //startActivity(intent);

            }

        });
```

Here is Department Class, which is a pure Java class

```
public class Department {
    private String deptName, deptUrl;


    public static final Department[] myDepartment = {

            new Department("CS", "http://cs.com"),
            new Department("Biology", "http://bio.com"),
            new Department("Chemistry", "http://www.chemistry.com"),
            new Department("Nursing", "http://nursing.com")
    };

    private Department(String deptName, String deptUrl){
        this.deptName = deptName;
        this.deptUrl = deptUrl;

    }

    public String getDeptName() {
        return deptName;
    }

    public String getDeptUrl() {
        return deptUrl;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return deptName;
    }

}
```

Department Fragment

```
public class DepartmentFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public DepartmentFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_department, container, false);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is [creating a DialogFragment] different than creating list with ListFragment

Simply: Yes.

Why? Because `ListFragment` gives you access to both `getListView()` and `setAdapter()` and instance methods of the class.

In order to do that with any other Fragment class that does not extend from `ListFragment`, you must declare some XML layout with a `ListView` and do something like this

I'll assume `fragment_department.xml` contains a `ListView` element of `@+id/list` and that you do not care about how the Department information is displayed.

```
public class DepartmentFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public DepartmentFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_department, container, false);

        ListView lstView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

        ArrayAdapter<Department> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Department>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Department.myDepartment);
        lstView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // TODO: adapter.setOnItemClickListener 
        //    ... handle click
        //    ... load webpage

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your model must implements Parcelable:

```
public class Department implements Parcelable {
    private String deptName, deptUrl;


    public static final Department[] myDepartment = {

            new Department("CS", "http://cs.com"),
            new Department("Biology", "http://bio.com"),
            new Department("Chemistry", "http://www.chemistry.com"),
            new Department("Nursing", "http://nursing.com")
    };

    private Department(String deptName, String deptUrl){
        this.deptName = deptName;
        this.deptUrl = deptUrl;

    }

    protected Department(Parcel in) {
        deptName = in.readString();
        deptUrl = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<Department> CREATOR = new Creator<Department>() {
        @Override
        public Department createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Department(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Department[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Department[size];
        }
    };

    public String getDeptName() {
        return deptName;
    }

    public String getDeptUrl() {
        return deptUrl;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return deptName;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeString(deptName);
        parcel.writeString(deptUrl);
    }
}
```

After, you must implement the method:

```
btnDepartment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DepartmentFragment departmentFragment = DepartmentFragment.newInstance(department);
                departmentFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "departmentFragment");
            }

        });
```

And the fragment as follows:

```
public class DepartmentFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private Department department;

    public DepartmentFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static DepartmentFragment newInstance(Department department) {
        DepartmentFragment f = new DepartmentFragment();

        // Supply num input as an argument.
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelable("department", department);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        department = getArguments().getParcelable("department")
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_department, container, false);
    }

}
```

Also, you can check all information at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html